# how to add AutoGenerateEditButton="True" in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-4.5, auto-generate

I am creating a grid view dynamically and everything works perfect. But i can't seem to add this property in my code behind when i create the DataGrid. Is there something that i need to do in order to allow this?

```
DataGrid DG = new DataGrid();
DG.ID = "test";
// This doesn't allow me to add this
DG.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
DG.DataSource = tbl;
DG.DataBind();
```

I can see that option when i add a grid view to my aspx page, but in code behind i can't seem to add it.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "can't seem to add it".  Is it not showing up at runtime, you're getting an error during compilation, etc ...

Comment: in visual studio, when i try to add that, it comes up as red and doesn't compile, its says that property doesn't exist. I've been doing some research on this, and i found something that says that datatables can't work with that, and that it needs to be a sqldatasource, is it possible to convert a datatable to sqldatasource, if thats really the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are using the `DataGrid` type which does not have a `AutoGenerateEditButton` property.  That property is present on the `GridView` class.  If you switch to using a `GridView` this code will compile (although it may cause other errors in parts of the code which aren't shown that depended on the type being `DataGrid`)

Comment: you're right, i just switched to gridview and i see the edit button, but how do i control it, in order to be able to edit?